# Windows phone, Using photocamera

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera

I looked at the microsoft documentation on how to create an camera application but i got lost quickly. Here is my question: 
How to make the screen show what the camera sees? Do you do this using canvas? I'm really stuck guys.. can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the sample camera app?

[How to create a base camera app for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx).

They use a Canvas and set the background of the Canvas to the Camera's output.  It is very simple to follow.  Remember to set the Camera Capability `<Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>` in the WMAppManifest.xml file.